Django Tastypie API Slow Response Time with Annotate Count and Pagination
I'm working with a Django Tastypie API that processes a large QuerySet. I need to perform an annotate with a Count on a related table, which is also very large.
Afterward, I return the response using paginator to handle the pagination. However, the API is taking a significant amount of time to return the results.
Here is a simplified version of the annotate that seems to be causing the most delay:
.annotate(
    dynm_calc=Count('devices', filter=Q(devices__groups__id__in=ids_list), distinct=True)
)

My main concerns are:

QuerySet Evaluation: Is the entire QuerySet being evaluated despite using pagination? If so, could this be the reason for the slow response times?

Performance Optimization: How can I optimize this query or improve the performance of the API response?

Splitting the QuerySet: Would splitting the QuerySet into smaller parts before applying the annotate be beneficial? If yes, how can this be effectively implemented?


Any insights or suggestions on how to tackle this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Do you have other annotations (I see distinct=True)? Can you share the related models?

No, I don't have.
It seems like Tastypie is evaluating the whole queryset even thought it has pagination.

Is it possible to add the related models?
